# get all channel info with youtube api and curl

Tags: json, curl, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hey guys i was perusing the youtube api documents and saw this json snippet right here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource-representation

I saw this and would like to grab all this info from the specified youtube channel in my curl code. So far all i wrote was this:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=[CHANNEL NAME]&key=[API KEY]"
```

but that only gives back a small part of that json, i think its the "statistics" part.

If yall can help that would be so kind, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the other info attached to a given channel, do mention the set of properties you're interested in via the `part` parameter, as specified by the [reference doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#part).

**Update:**

To get all the info available, the URL to be passed to `curl` would be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings,contentDetails,contentOwnerDetails,id,localizations,snippet,statistics,status,topicDetails&id=[CHANNEL NAME]&key=[API KEY]
```

Note that the `part` parameter does not contain `auditDetails` since that requires additional permissions.

Comment: Thanks friend however idk what is necessary to make the output the most detailed. I am sorry i am new to youtube api